# webpack.js is not found in laravel vue app?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, npm-install, laravel-7

i am using vue in laravel and trying run `npm run dev` but it is giving me this error

```
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'G:\\laravel-vuetify-spa-starter\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\utils\\convert-argv.js',
    'G:\\laravel-vuetify-spa-starter\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
    'G:\\laravel-vuetify-spa-starter\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'
  ]


npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpa
ck.config.js`
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "and": "0.0.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "npm": "^6.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.9",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "vuetify-toast-snackbar": "^0.6.1",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }
}
```

How i can solve this issue ?

Comment: Edit the question and add the content of `package.json`

Comment: added package.json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The development script in your `package.json` is attempting to load the webpack config from `laravel-mix` and you don't have it installed

```
"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules 
--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
```

Just install `laravel-mix` or create your own webpack config

```sh
npm i laravel-mix
```

And make sure that you have `webpack.mix.js` on the root directory if you decide to use the mix wrapper

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: how to import external css files in vue component? @import '../css/style.css'; throws error  Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js): Error: Can't resolve '../images/menu/icon/light-close.png' in 'K:\vue\laravel-vue-auth\resources\css'